# gooAccess my storage bucket from C# .NET Application

Tags: c#, .net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to read an XML file stored on my Bucket using an C# .NET application but it sometimes works and most of the time i get Timeout error or "The underlying connection was closed", noting that i can read the file using any internet browser.

I read it using the following line:

```
xmlFile.Load(@"https://storage-download.googleapis.com/bucket_name/file.xml");
```

Comment: Hello ,  The link can be read in a browser where you are logged in with a google account

Comment: you need to create a link which should not required an account logged in. I have seen this option while creating link in Onedrive. You should explore it on google drive(it available there also)

Comment: I can access it on browser where i am not logged on to my account

Comment: not just your account any of a google account must be logged in the browser so you are being able to open the link. I am getting 404 ERROR

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda no other accounts are logged in and i can access that link